# Prevent UITableView (subview of UIScrollView) from swallowing touches on embedded UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionview

I am aware that variants of this question have been asked and answered ad nauseam. But I think have a fairly unusual view stack, and suggested solutions for the variants haven't worked:

1. I have a UIScrollView, embedding a UITableView, which has UITableViewCells, each of which embeds a UICollectionView.
2. I want to enable horizontal scrolling on each UICollectionView, via a horizontal swipe, and taps on the UICollectionViewCells inside the UICollectionView, via a tap.

But neither tap nor swipe works. But as far as I can test, either the super-parent UIScrollView or the parent UITableView is swallowing the touches. Other elements in each UITableViewCell respond to touch (and scrolling vertically in the UITableView works fine), so I know that whatever is doing the swallowing is not swallowing everything. Even when I add a tap gesture recognizer to the collection view, for testing purposes, nothing comes through.

What's the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a UIScrollView?
The UITableView has a vertical scroll by default, so a UIScrollView might mess something up.

I am not completely sure, and not able to test right now, but try removing the UIScrollView.
Worth a shot, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the scrollview is providing horizontal scrolling among multiple table views. So I can't get rid of it.